# Sum int values from a child table to parent Index List in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to solve a problem:

I don't know how to access the cnt value from my query, or how to rewrite it for use in my project

```
Select * from samples as s INNER JOIN (SELECT sampleId, SUM(quantity) cnt FROM locationsamples GROUP BY sampleID) sl ON sl.sampleID=s.SampleId;
```

The query above gives me the information I need.

How do I access the Summed cnt value from my controller so that I can read it in my view?

```
public class samples
{
[Key]
    public int SampleId { get; set; }

    //many to many relationship for locations (one sample can be in many locations, with a quantity in each)
    public virtual ICollection<locationsamples> locationsamples { get; set; 
 }

public class locationsamples
{
    public int locationsamplesID { get; set; }

    public int locationID { get; set; }
    public virtual location location { get; set; }

    public int sampleID { get; set; }
    public virtual sample sample { get; set; }

    public int quantity { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You msut group by on locationsamples, then select aggregation fields that you required. what you want is something like this:

```
var list = dbContext.locationsamples
    .GroupBy(e => e.sampleID)
    .Select(group => new
    {
        SampleId = group.key,
        Cnt = group.Sum(c => c.quantity),
    }).ToList();
```